# C/C++ Optimizing compiler corrupted due to use of template

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have `Foo` and `Bar` as follows:

Foo.h

```
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
private:
    template <typename BarT>
    list<BarT*> barT_lst;

public:
    template <typename BarT>
    Foo(void);

    ~Foo(void);
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"

template <typename BarT>
Foo::Foo(void)
{
}

Foo::~Foo(void)
{
}
```

Bar.h

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(void);
    ~Bar(void);
};

Bar::Bar(void)
{
}

Bar::~Bar(void)
{
}
```

And main()

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Foo<Bar> foo = Foo<Bar>();
    return 0;
}
```

I use VC++2008. Every time when I build project, it shows errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>Test.cpp
1>c:\users\duong2179\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\test\test\foo.h(12) : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>(compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1411)
1> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ 
1> Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\duong2179\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Test\Test\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Test - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

[image: Build error]

This looks very strange. Please help!

Comment: Try upgrading to a more recent version of compiler

Comment: BTW `template <typename BarT> list<BarT*> barT_lst;` is invalid code - there is no such thing as template member variables

Comment: @M.M How can I declare list of BarT for such a thing?

Comment: You can't - how would you specify the parameter?  Maybe you mean to have `BarT` as a template parameter for `Foo`.  (`Foo<Bar>` is also illegal because `Foo` is not a template)

Comment: @M.M Okay. I intend to make something to be able to inititate `Foo<Bar> foo = Foo<Bar>();` as shown in main. Could you please show me how I can do it?

Comment: Consider switching to a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/); both are free software, and support recent C++ standards (e.g. C++14 at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting an access violation from the compiler should not really happen, it would be good to upgrade compiler.

However your code is also illegal. If you intend to write `Foo<Bar> foo;` then `Foo` needs to be a template, for example:

```
template<typename BarT>
class Foo
{
    std::list<BarT *> barT_lst;
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
};

template<typename BarT>
Foo<BarT>::Foo() 
{
    // constructor code here
}
```

Note: this class probably violates [Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) , you should not have a container of raw pointers unless those pointers do not own what they are pointing to. (In which case you don't need a destructor).

Comment: If so, it also requires to declare destructor like `Foo<Bar>::~Foo()` right?

Comment: @duong_dajgja to *define* destructor out-of-line, you need to do that, yes.

Comment: Also note that the out-of-line function bodies cannot just sit in a .cpp file, they must be visible (or an explicit instantiation visible) to all code which calls them. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the implementation of Foo class in same Foo.h file, i.e after class declaration.

Comment: I did. It did not help.

Comment: Sorry that was typo, put Foo class in Foo.h